# The limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+3x-4}-x$

Tags: calculus, limits, arithmetic, radicals

I tried all I know and I always get to $\infty$, Wolfram Alpha says $\frac{3}{2}$. How should I simplify it?

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{(x^2+3x+4)}-x$$

I tried multiplying by its conjugate, taking the squared root out of the limit, dividing everything by $\sqrt{x^2}$, etc.

Obs.: Without using l'Hôpital's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} - x & = \left(\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} - x \right) \times \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x}{\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x}\\
& = \dfrac{(\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} - x)(\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x)}{\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x}\\
& = \dfrac{x^2+3x-4-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x} = \dfrac{3x-4}{\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} + x}\\
& = \dfrac{3-4/x}{\sqrt{1+3/x-4/x^2} + 1}
\end{align}
Now we get
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+3x-4} - x & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{3-4/x}{\sqrt{1+3/x-4/x^2} + 1}\\
& = \dfrac{3-\lim_{x \to \infty} 4/x}{1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{1+3/x-4/x^2} } = \dfrac{3}{1+1}\\
& = \dfrac32
\end{align}

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking your time friend, I realized that I was working with $+1$ instead of $+x$ all the time. Thank you for your kind answer and sorry for this.

Answer (score 6):

Intuitively you can see this as follows:

Write $x^2+3x+4$ as $\left(x+\frac32\right)^2+\frac74$. For $x$ large this quantity is almost the same as $\left(x+\frac32\right)^2$. Therefore for $x$ large $\sqrt{x^2+3x+4}-x\sim\sqrt{\left(x+\frac32\right)^2}-x=\frac32$

Answer (score 4):

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(x^2 + 3x + 4\right)^{ \frac{1}{2}} - x $$
$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(x^2\left(1+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)\right)^{ \frac{1}{2}} - x $$
$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\left(1+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^{ \frac{1}{2}} - x $$

Then by Taylor expansion, we get that

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{x}+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)+\operatorname{o}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right) - x $$

$$ = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{2} + \operatorname{o}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{3}{2} $$

as required.