# Finding $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x$ results in loss of information

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x$

Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x^2-5x+1-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}+x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{-5x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}+x}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\dfrac{-5x+1}{x}}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}+x}{x}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{-5+\dfrac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{x^2}-\dfrac{5}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^2}}+1}$$

From here, I know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{x} = 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{5}{x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2} = 0$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{-5}{\sqrt{1}+1}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{-5}{2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \dfrac{-5}{2}$$

Everything up to here seems fine. The issue is when I try to find $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)$

I also know that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{1}{x} = 0$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{5}{x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2} = 0$

This would make me conclude that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = \dfrac{-5}{2}$.

However, this is not the case because $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = \infty$

[Desmos view of $f(x)$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cwm1o3zzu6)

Why am I arriving to the wrong answer and how can I algebraically prove that the answer is $\infty$?

Comment: Do you want $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cdots$ or $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\cdots$?

Comment: When dealing with limits at $-\infty$ often is convenient change variable in order to deal with a limit at $\infty$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am only interested in $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}$

Comment: Ah! You wrote $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}}x=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}-\frac{5}x+\frac{1}{x^2}!}!!$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627427/puzzled-by-displaystyle-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2x-x/627671#627671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as understanding, you have, in essence,
$$ \left| x - \frac{5}{2} \right|   - x  .  $$
for large positive $x$ you get close to $-5/2,$ but for large negative $x,$ meaning $x$ is negative and $|x|$ is large, you have roughly 
$$ 2 |x| + \frac{5}{2}  $$
which grows without bound. For example, if $x = -10,$ the original expression becomes
$$ \sqrt{100 - (-50) + 1} - (-10) = \sqrt {151} + 10 \approx 22.2882 $$
If $x = -100,$
$$ \sqrt{10000 - (-500) + 1} - (-100) = \sqrt {10501} + 100 \approx 202.474 $$
If $x = -1000,$
$$ \sqrt{1000000 - (-5000) + 1} - (-1000) = \sqrt {1005001} + 1000 \approx 2002.49738 $$

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to quickly see that the result is unbounded without jumping to conclusions on the wrong answer like I did?

Comment: @CedricMartens  probably not quick. Just that the square root term amounts, more or less,  to an absolute value. Think about $|x| - x,$ how could you express that without any absolute value signs in case (I) $x > 0$ ? but then case (II) $x < 0$  ??

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

At $-\infty$, $x$ becomes negative, thus

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}}{-(-x)}=$$

$$-\sqrt{\frac{x^2-5x+1}{x^2}}.$$

the denominator goes to zero.

Comment: Wouldn't I arrive to the answer $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = \dfrac{5}{2}$ while doing so?

Comment: At $+\infty,  \sqrt{x^2}=x$   but at $-\infty$ you should have $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$.

Comment: @CedricMartens: you will get the answer $-5/(-\sqrt{1}+1)$ when $x\to-\infty $

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $x\to -\infty$

- $\sqrt{x^2-5x+1} \to +\infty$
- $-x \to +\infty$

and therefore

$$\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x \to +\infty$$

As an alternative by $x=-y\to -\infty$ with $y\to +\infty$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2-5x+1}-x=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\sqrt{y^2+5y+1}+y \to +\infty$$